# Is it possible to use the Twilio SMS API authenticated with API Key?

Tags: authentication, twilio, sms

The [SMS API example code](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api?code-sample=code-send-a-simple-sms-using-the-programmable-sms-api&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) works by create a client session using an account SID and an auth token:

```js
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
```

However in the [example code shown here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/keys/api-key?code-sample=code-authenticate-with-api-key-and-api-secret&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) a `client` is being initialised using accountSid, API Key and API Secret:

```js
const client = require('twilio')(twilioApiKey, twilioApiSecret, {
    accountSid: twilioAccountSid });
```

but using this with SMS-service credentials fails to authenticate.

Is the SMS API only authenticate-able using an accountSid with an auth token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your second code sample should work. Please make sure the ApiKey, ApiSecret and AccountSid are set and match the information on your account.

Try extending your code:

```js
const accountSid = "...";
const apiKey = "...";
const apiSecret = "...";
const client = require('twilio')(apiKey, apiSecret, { accountSid: accountSid });


client.messages
  .create({
    body: 'Hello from Node',
    to: '<put your phone number here>', // Text this number
    from: '<put the account phone number here>', // From a valid Twilio number
  })
  .then((message) => console.log(message.sid));
```

This should log the message ID if successful.